# Simple Trigonometric Equation

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos 2\theta=(\sqrt2+1)(\cos\theta-1/\sqrt2)$, then what is the value of $\theta$ ?

I don't know how to solve this question. can someone tell me the required steps to solve this question.

Comment: The equation mixes $\cos2\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ terms, making it apparently insoluble. If you can express one in terms of the other (check your table f formulas), you can improve on that.

Answer (score 3):

Use $\cos 2x = 2(\cos x)^2  -1$ and get quadratic in $\cos x$ then proceed

Answer (score 3):

You have $$\cos 2\theta=\cos^2 \theta-\sin^2\theta=2\cos^2\theta -1$$
Calling $x=\cos\theta$, you get
$$2x^2-1=(\sqrt{2}+1)\left(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=(\sqrt{2}+1)x-\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$
Since it simplifies to
$$x^2-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{2}+1)x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=0$$
Since the discriminant
$$\Delta=\frac{3}{4\sqrt{2}}(\sqrt{2}-4)<0$$
there are no solutions.

Comment: I think you forgot to divide by $2$ the constant term. It should be $$x^2-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{2}+1)x+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}=0$$ which has two real solutions.